# How to make a prediction task based on the data without label using Weka software

Tags: database

I have a dataset that includes about 20 columns and a million rows. Each row represents the results of one different scenario and each column shows a result of a feature of our model. I have copied a small section of our database below.
[image: Here is the subset of my database]

my question is, how can I check the accuracy of my model for prediction any of the results (columns) using Weka software. I know if I have a label for each scenario, I can use the classification method and can easily calculate the accuracy of the prediction of labels such as the "Status" column in my dataset. But for instance, I want to check out the prediction task accuracy for anticipating the "PGA" column values. I tried to make my question clear but if is still somethings unclear please let me know. I'm really struggling with this issue.
Looking forward to your answers,
Best.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you can use Clustering, then use Weka's "ClusterToClassification" Filter to add a new attribute, make this the "class attribute" (= the response variable), then do some classification tasks to predict cluster membership. for instance.

I can give only a general strategy here because you haven't indicated what eactly you want to predict (a categorical or a numerical value) andwhat metric you are after...

But I hope this can get you started.

But IMHO this forum is not the right place to ask this question. THis belongs to the datascience.SE or (more specifically asked) to Stackoverflow.com.